# Why intuitively does $\mathbb E(\frac d {d\theta}\log p_\theta(x))=0$?

Tags: probability, intuition, integral

Let $p_\theta(x)$ be the probability density function of $x$. Then obviously, $\frac d{d\theta}\mathbb E(1)=0$. But note that $\mathbb E(1)=\int p_\theta(x)dx$, so that $\frac d{d\theta}\mathbb E(1)=\int p_\theta(x)\frac d{d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)dx=\mathbb E\left (\frac d{d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)\right)=0$.

**Is there an intuitive explanation for why this final equation is true?**

Comment: For many people, the derivation you give is perfectly "intuitive," so could you elaborate on what you mean by this term?

Comment: @whuber, I mean an explanation that states a meaning of $\log p_\theta(x)$, and why we should expect this object to be zero. in other words, and explanation of the equation that allows one to see that it is true immediately, simply by interpreting the formula, rather than by deriving it from something else.

Comment: Why is $\frac d{d\theta}\mathbb E(1)=0$ obvious?

Comment: @RahulDeora, because $\mathbb E(1)=1$, which doesn't depend on $\theta$

Comment: One difficulty is that the interpretation of the formula depends on the family in which $p_\theta$ is embedded.  One true general statement is that the set of all probability density functions is not unrestricted; in particular, they all lie on the "simplex" determined by the requirement to integrate to unity.  Whenever any family of quantities--probability distributions or not--is constrained by an equation, then under any variation within that family, the equation's value does not change.  Is that what you mean by "intuition," despite not having anything inherently to do with probability?

Comment: @whuber, I am not even sure how what you're saying relates to the equation. What you're saying seems to me to be an explanation for why $\frac d{d\theta}\mathbb E(1)=0$ is true, not why $\mathbb E[\frac d{d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)]=0$ is true.

Comment: Please explain to us what you mean by "intuitive," then: I offered my comments only in an effort to elicit that important information from you.

Comment: @whuber, I really don't know how more to explain it, and I'm surprised that it's this unclear. To rephrase my previous explanation: I am looking for an understanding that is based directly on the meaning of $\frac d {d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)$, of why its expectation should be zero. I.e. the understanding should directly rely on the semantics of $\frac d {d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)$, rather than on the semantics of a syntactically derived equivalent statement. Isn't this literally **always** what is meant by "the intuition" of a theorem?

Comment: No, that's the problem.  By "intuition" some people mean "in a way that could be understood by the proverbial five-year-old or grandmother;" others mean using a visualization of some sort; others mean reducing it to a series of obvious, simple algebraic steps; others more generally mean by finding a morphism between the original question and a completely different problem; and so on.  In short, "intuition" is both subjective and personal, so the more clearly you can describe the kind of answers you seek, the more likely you are to get them.

Comment: In this case, as I attempted to point out earlier, there is no inherent meaning to $\theta,$ whence there is no inherent meaning to $\frac{d}{d\theta}\log p_\theta(x).$ This suggests that any explanation, intuitive or not, must rest on additional suppositions about the family of models indexed by $\theta.$  But generally, in *all* such models the probabilities integrate to unity--and ultimately that is the *only* fully general basis for the result.

Comment: @whuber, ok let's say $p_\theta$ is the normal distribution and $\theta$ is the mean. Btw I don't agree that there being no inherent meaning to $\theta$ implies that there is no inherent meaning to $\frac d {dθ}\log p_θ(x)$. It means something like, the percentage change in the probability of $x$ due to a change in the parameter.

Comment: That's a nice interpretation (understanding, where necessary, that you mean probability *density*).  From that perspective, its zero expectation is a statement that on average the total probability doesn't change.  Since total probability must constantly be unity, that's obvious--provided we use the right definition of "on average."  Thus, this result can be conceived of as a demonstration that the "right" way to average $\frac{d}{d\theta}\log p_\theta(x)$ is with respect to $p_\theta.$

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to be a little careful. Suppose $X \sim p_{\theta_0}(x)$ and define $s(\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \log p_\theta(X)$. Then what we have is 
$\mathbb E\{s(X; \theta_0)\} = 0$.

For intuition, suppose we have $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ iid from $p_{\theta_0}$ with $\theta_0$ unknown. A natural approach to estimating $\theta_0$ is to maximize the log-likelihood function
$$
\ell(\theta) = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \log p_\theta(X_i). 
$$
Intuitively, this should be (approximately) maximized at $\theta_0$. This implies that $\theta_0$ should (approximately) be a critical point of $\ell(\theta)$, i.e., 
$$
\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n s(X_i; \theta_0) \approx 0. 
$$
The score equation is the "population-level" statement of this intuition - as $n \to \infty$, the law of large numbers suggests
$$
\mathbb E\{s(X_1; \theta_0)\} = 0.
$$
Following this logic further, define the *population level log-likelihood* by 
$$
\ell^\star(\theta) = \mathbb E\{\log p_\theta(X_1)\}
$$
where recall that the $X_i$'s *are distributed according to $\theta_0$*. The same intuition suggests that $\ell^\star(\theta)$ is maximized at $\theta_0$, and indeed this is true by Jensen's inequality:
$$
\mathbb E\{\log p_{\theta_0}(X)\} - \mathbb E\{\log p_\theta(X)\}
=
\mathbb E\left\{-\log \frac{p_\theta(X)}{p_{\theta_0}(X)}\right\}
\ge 
-\log \mathbb \int \frac{p_\theta(x)}{p_{\theta_0}(x)} \, p_{\theta_0}(x) \ dx = 0. 
$$

Comment: An interesting thing about the later intuition is that it is true under essentially no conditions (aside from some support condition maybe) - no interchange of integrals and derivatives necessary. This suggests that it is really the more fundamental fact, and the score equation being a consequence of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at an information theoretic explanation. It relies on the principle that, when encoding samples from a distribution, the shortest code is the one designed based on the true underlying distribution of the samples. Using what you know about the true distribution, you can do the best possible job allocating short codes to common samples and long codes to rare samples. Your friend, who doesn't know the true distribution and accidentally uses long codes for common words, ends up wasting their bandwidth.

To understand this answer, you also need to know that the optimal code uses a word of length $\log_2 P(x|\theta)$ bits to encode $x$. This is exactly true for discrete distributions with probabilities of the form $2^{-k}$. It is kinda-sorta-mostly-true-especially-when-you-have-many-samples for other, more complicated distributions.

To see how this applies, notice the expectation of the score can be approximated by a Monte Carlo algorithm: sample $x_1, ... x_n$ from $P(X|\theta)$ and evaluate $\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{1}{n}\sum_i  \log (P(x_i|\theta))$. All I did was turn the integral into a Monte Carlo approximation. In the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, this whole thing converges to $0$, and we want intuition for why it does that.

But, squinting at this, it is the derivative of the average code length per sample (up to a constant, since it's a natural log and not a base-2 log). Since we're using the ground-truth $\theta$, the code can't get any more efficient. Any change in $\theta$ leads to a more verbose encoding. So the average code length $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_i  \log (P(x_i|\theta))$ is optimal.

What's the only thing you remember from calculus? The derivative at the optimum is zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only amounts to a clever disguise of the original unwanted proof, substituting Monte Carlo samples for an expectation and substituting hand-waving about information theory for hand-waving about analysis. Take an integral, boom it's a constant, boom, derivative equals zero. Terrible answer! This user should be ejected from the site! Hee hee.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by look at the classical proof of this expectation result.  Under regularity conditions that allow the interchange of integration and differentiation, you have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_\theta(X) \Big)
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \cdot \frac{1}{p_\theta(x)} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d\theta} \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d\theta} 1 = 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Giving intuitive explanations for mathematical results is inherently difficult, since one has to speculate to some degree on the thinking of the questioner.  I have been thinking about this question to see where the intuitive difficulty comes in, so that I can give an explanation here.  At the risk of misunderstanding your concerns, I note that, aside from simple algebra, the above reasoning for the result hinges one two results: (1) the interchange of the integral and derivative; and (2) the general form for the derivative of the logarithm of a function, which is:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \log f(\theta) = \frac{f'(\theta)}{f(\theta)}.$$

This latter result gives you:

$$f(\theta) \times \frac{d}{d\theta} \log f(\theta) = f'(\theta),$$

and this property then gives the result of interest via the above proof.  So I think what you're essentially asking is for an intuitive explanation of why the derivative of the logarithm has this form.  One way to see why this is is to go back to the first principles definition of the logarithm and apply [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), to obtain:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \log f(\theta) 
= \frac{d}{d\theta} \int \limits_1^{f(\theta)} \frac{dr}{r}
= \frac{1}{f(\theta)} \times \frac{d}{d\theta} f(\theta)
= \frac{f'(\theta)}{f(\theta)}.$$

You can find a visual depiction of Liebniz integral rule in [Frantz (2018)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.2001.11953053), and that may assist in understanding the intuition for this last step.  Once you understand the intuition of this application of the Leibniz rule, you can see why the derivative of the logarithm has the form that it does, which immediately shows why the produce of the derivative of the logarithm times the original function is equal to the derivative of the function.  The resulting expected value property then follows immediately.

---

**Putting this all together:** We can write the proof of the result in an expanded form that uses multiple applicates of the Leibniz integral rule.  Assuming that $\mathscr{X}$ does not depend on $\theta$, we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_\theta(X) \Big)
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_\theta(x) \bigg) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int \limits_1^{p_\theta(x)} \frac{dr}{r} \bigg) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \bigg( \frac{1}{p_\theta(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p_\theta(x) - 1 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} 1 + \int \limits_1^{p_\theta(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \frac{dr}{r} \bigg) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \bigg( \frac{1}{p_\theta(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p_\theta(x) - 0+0 \bigg) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathscr{X} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d \theta} \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_\theta(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d \theta} 1 = 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

As you can see, this requires nothing more than repeated applications of Leibniz integral rule, so the appropriate "intuition" is intuition about why this rule holds.

Comment: Yes, intuition is in the brain of the beholder! Since an integral is the area under a curve, I am mainly hoping for answers to decompose this area in a way that explains why it has equal parts above and below the axis, rather than sticking with the original proof, which never does that.

Comment: @eric That's the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, because the expectation is the integral of $p^\prime(\theta).$  There seems to be little point in geometrically demonstrating the FTC in this special case, because that would illuminate neither the statistical nor the mathematical aspects of the situation.

Comment: Your notation $p'(\theta)$ obscures the fact that the derivative is w.r.t. the second argument, whereas the integral is w.r.t. the first. This troubles me. If this fact $E_{\theta_0}[s(x,\theta_0)]=0$ is a special case of the FTC, why is it true for discrete distributions too? How can it just be about the FTC if there's no integral involved?

Comment: The proof in the question looks more like an instance of theorem 2 from 
http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf

Comment: @eric_kernfeld: It obscures that fact to *simplify* the presentation, and thus get to the heart of the intuition behind what is happening inside the integral.

Comment: I think the key miscommunication here is that I'm talking about "the integral" in the question, w.r.t. $x$, but you're talking about "the integral" in the definition of the natural log. Does that change how you interpret my comments?

Comment: The outer integral does not really do anything except integrate over the density function to get a value of one.  (I think we confused the issue by mentioning the FTC here, since it isn't really relevant.)  I am assuming that the intuition that is needed is not for this part, since that is a trivial property of the density function. As such, my intuitive explanation focuses on the intuition required to simplify the integrand.  I have expanded the answer to show the full proof, in case this helps.