# Intuitively, why is the expectation of the score 0?

Tags: self-study, intuition, likelihood, scoring-rules

Given a probability model $p(x|\theta)$, the score function is typically defined as $\frac{d}{d\theta} \log p(x|\theta)$.  The expectation $\mathbb{E}[\frac{d}{d\theta} \log p(X|\theta)]$ is zero under some regularity conditions, and this plays an important role in likelihood-based statistics. The usual proof of this fact is:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d}{d\theta} \log (p(x|\theta)) p(x|\theta) dx 
&= \int \frac{\frac{d}{d\theta} p(x|\theta) }{p(x|\theta)} p(x|\theta) dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \frac{d}{d\theta} p(x|\theta) dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d\theta}\int p(x|\theta) dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{d}{d\theta} 1 = 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

This assures me that it's true, at least when the integral and derivative can be exchanged, but it doesn't help me understand why. An integral is the area under a curve. Can anyone decompose this area in a way that explains why it has equal parts above and below the axis? Or is there another way to develop intuition here?

Comment: Same question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414317/119261.